# how to create vertical and horizontal scrollbar on top-level window python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new in Python.
I create vertical and horizontal scroll bar with the help of a post. 
When I resize the toplevel window then scrollbar does't move.
How to make scroll bar move with resizing window. Thanks

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

top=Toplevel(root)
text = Text(top)
vs = Scrollbar(top, orient="vertical")
hs = Scrollbar(top, orient="horizontal")
sizegrip = ttk.Sizegrip(root)

# hook up the scrollbars to the text widget
text.configure(yscrollcommand=vs.set, xscrollcommand=hs.set, wrap="none")
vs.configure(command=text.yview)
hs.configure(command=text.xview)

# grid everything on-screen
text.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="news")
vs.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="ns")
hs.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="news")
sizegrip.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="news")
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

def fill():
    for n in range(30):
        text.insert("end", 'check scroll bar ' * 20, "", "\n")


Button(root, text='press', command=fill).grid(row=0, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the Toplevel to adjust the cell in row=0, column=0 when the window is resized:

```
# grid everything on-screen
top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Comment: I further need to know, how to move scroll bar up and down using wheel of mouse

Comment: Doesn't it work? It works just fine for me. Mouse wheel scrolls up/down and SHIFT+Mouse wheel scrolls left/right. Maybe it's the platform; I'm on Python 3.6.5 on win10.

Comment: I use Python 3.6 on win 7. Mouse wheel doesn't work for me  to move scroll bars.